# Is Rounded Corners on Attributed Text Background possible?

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel, nsattributedstring, quartz-core

I attributed Text with different textcolors. For better readability on highlighted text i use backgroundcolor. 
Is it possible to bring the CALayer Effect of Rounded Corners on this Textarea? Not the whole Area but the special Text inside of it.

My Code:

```
NSAttributedString *text = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Highlighted Text"
                                                                          attributes:@{
                                                                                       NSFontAttributeName:            [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10.0f],
                                                                                       NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor],
                                                                                       NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor darkGrayColor]
                                                                                       }];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSAttributedString background color and rounded corners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362407/nsattributedstring-background-color-and-rounded-corners)

Comment: Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857408/how-to-set-nsstrings-background-cornerradius-on-ios7