# NSAttributedString with Corner Radius and Word Wrap?

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring, core-text

I have tried a lot to have a `NSAttributedString` with Background image and making a corner radius for it . Basically i want to achieve the same result as BASECAMP to-do . it shows task name with the assigned person and comments on that task . the assigned person or comments changes the line if it don't fit the same line .

I am using the `UILabel` inside the `UITableViewCell` which resizes as per the content. So i need to use the same `UILabel` . And change the Text inside the UIlabel to achieve the Basecamp To-do list.

[image]

Comment: Couldn't add photo as per my reputation points [link] (http://i60.tinypic.com/33pf1bd.jpg)

Comment: What problem are you facing here exactly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSAttributedString background color and rounded corners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362407/nsattributedstring-background-color-and-rounded-corners)

Comment: @n00bProgrammer : I am not able to have that curve as background and the content should wrap to another line if it does'nt fit in same line. it should not break in between.

Comment: @ujell: I guess giving layer.cornerRadius is not possible for NSattributedString.

Comment: It's possible but little bit tricky. You may also want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857408/how-to-set-nsstrings-background-cornerradius-on-ios7

Comment: @ujell : I will try it , But what about wrapping of word. I can elaborate about what i mean by wrapping the word condition.

Comment: CoreText can help ? if Yes. How ?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure for both of them. Alternatively, you can consider adding different labels to end of the first label.