# UITextField rounded corner text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Is there any way to add an array of strings with rounded corners and grey background color. but the last string is without these attributes on my UITextField using attributed text only?
[image: Reference picture for my UITextField]

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: I was trying this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857408/how-to-set-nsstrings-background-cornerradius-on-ios7 but it's for a textview not a textfield this way I couldn't implement the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change my UITextField to UITextView and then used the solution from [How to set NSString's background cornerRadius on iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857408/how-to-set-nsstrings-background-cornerradius-on-ios7) and I did some tweaks using the UITextView delegate.

```
@implementation MyLayoutManager
- (void)fillBackgroundRectArray:(const CGRect *)rectArray count:(NSUInteger)rectCount forCharacterRange:(NSRange)charRange color:(UIColor *)color
{
    CGFloat halfLineWidth = 4.; // change this to change corners radius

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    if (rectCount == 1
        || (rectCount == 2 && (CGRectGetMaxX(rectArray[1]) < CGRectGetMinX(rectArray[0])))
        )
    {
        // 1 rect or 2 rects without edges in contact

        CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectInset(rectArray[0], halfLineWidth, halfLineWidth));
        if (rectCount == 2)
            CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectInset(rectArray[1], halfLineWidth, halfLineWidth));
    }
    else
    {
        // 2 or 3 rects
        NSUInteger lastRect = rectCount - 1;

        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(rectArray[0]) + halfLineWidth, CGRectGetMaxY(rectArray[0]) + halfLineWidth);

        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(rectArray[0]) + halfLineWidth, CGRectGetMinY(rectArray[0]) + halfLineWidth);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(rectArray[0]) - halfLineWidth, CGRectGetMinY(rectArray[0]) + halfLineWidth);

        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(rectArray[0]) - halfLineWidth, CGRectGetMinY(rectArray[lastRect]) - halfLineWidth);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(rectArray[lastRect]) - halfLineWidth, CGRectGetMinY(rectArray[lastRect]) - halfLineWidth);

        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(rectArray[lastRect]) - halfLineWidth, CGRectGetMaxY(rectArray[lastRect]) - halfLineWidth);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(rectArray[lastRect]) + halfLineWidth, CGRectGetMaxY(rectArray[lastRect]) - halfLineWidth);

        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(rectArray[lastRect]) + halfLineWidth, CGRectGetMaxY(rectArray[0]) + halfLineWidth);

        CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    }

    [color set]; // set fill and stroke color

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, halfLineWidth * 2.);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(ctx, kCGLineJoinRound);

    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path);
    CGPathRelease(path);

    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFillStroke);
}
@end

    - (void)updateHeaderWithText:(NSString*) text {
        // setup text handling
        NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:text];

        // use our subclass of NSLayoutManager
        MyLayoutManager *textLayout = [[MyLayoutManager alloc] init];

        [textStorage addLayoutManager:textLayout];

        NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];

        [textLayout addTextContainer:textContainer];
        UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, 30.0) textContainer:textContainer];
        self.navigationItem.titleView = textView;
        // set some background color to our text
        NSInteger rangeInitPlace = 0;
        for (NSString *word in self.namesArray) {
            if (![word isEqualToString:@" , "]) {
                [textView.textStorage setAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forKey:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName] range:NSMakeRange(rangeInitPlace, word.length)];
            }
            rangeInitPlace += word.length;
        }
        textView.delegate = self;
        [textView becomeFirstResponder];
        textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange([textView.text length], 0);
    }

-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    NSRange selectedRange = textView.selectedRange;

    UITextPosition *beginning = textView.beginningOfDocument;
    UITextPosition *start = [textView positionFromPosition:beginning offset:selectedRange.location];
    UITextPosition *end = [textView positionFromPosition:start offset:selectedRange.length];

    UITextRange* textRange = [textView.tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:end withGranularity:UITextGranularityWord inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionLeft];

    NSLog(@"Word that is currently being edited is : %@", [textView textInRange:textRange]);
    NSDictionary *normalAttrdict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor brownColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
    textView.typingAttributes = normalAttrdict;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: How can I do this, if the UItextView is in a storyboard??

Answer (score 0):

Try [zftokenfield](https://github.com/zoonooz/ZFTokenField) you can change the UI of this component as per your requirements

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift Developers**

It may be helpful  sometime.

[Rounded Corner](https://github.com/khawars/KSTokenView)