# How to set up roundRect backgroundColor about characters correctly in NSTextView?

Tags: ios, uitextview, nstextview, core-text, textkit

I want to set up roundRect backgroundColor for the important characters in NSTextView. The attribute is "tag". I override the func `fillBackgroundRectArray(_:count:forCharacterRange:color:)` of the **NSLayoutManager **. the code like below:

```
    override func fillBackgroundRectArray(_ rectArray: UnsafePointer<NSRect>, count rectCount: Int, forCharacterRange charRange: NSRange, color: NSColor) {

    var effectiveRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0)
    let attributes = self.textStorage?.attributes(at: charRange.location, effectiveRange: &effectiveRange)
    if attributes?.index(forKey: NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: "tag")) != nil {
        let bezierPath = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: rectArray[0], xRadius: 8, yRadius: 8)
        bezierPath.fill()
    } else {
        super.fillBackgroundRectArray(rectArray, count: rectCount, forCharacterRange: charRange, color: color)
    }
}
```

and the effect is：

[image]

But when i edit to tag("panic" to "paniddc" ) "panic", the effect is not my wish. the effect is ：

[image]

i wish the effect is :
[image]

**I want to know why? and what should I do to accomplish the last effect when I editing the tag?**

and my project is Here: [github](https://github.com/milocode/roundRect.git)

Comment: Unfortunately, your link is no longer valid. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I am having a similar problem... Did u solve this?

Comment: This probably will answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857408/how-to-set-nsstrings-background-cornerradius-on-ios7