# How can to have a view within the text of a textView? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, textview

I would like to implement a textView to show text in my app. But I need to replace every text which is in [ ] with a custom view, like in the picture shown. Is this possible with a UITextView, or are there other ways to archive this in swift?

[Example of what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF6q2.png)

I hope you can help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362407/nsattributedstring-background-color-and-rounded-corners ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857408/how-to-set-nsstrings-background-cornerradius-on-ios7 ?

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to do what I wanted!