# Find CGRect of a substring

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I want to get the coordinates of a substring of attributed text. This is a simplified version of the premise.

```
// Content
NSString *haystack = @"This is a paragraph of moderate length. I want to find a specific word within it. And then draw on top of that Word a rectangular shape.";
NSString *needle = @"word";

// Finding the needle
NSRange range = [haystack rangeOfString:needle];
range.location; // 66
range.length;   // 4

// Draw it
UILabel *label;
label.text = haystack;
```

The range only gives me a character-wise location of the needle within the haystack. I need a bounding CGRect of the needle. Here's what I want to achieve, having this `UILabel`.

<kbd>[image: Before]</kbd>

Draw a rounded rect over the **needle**.

<kbd>[image: After]</kbd>

Comment: I am thinking, take a screenshot, do character recognition using Tesseract. Get the cordinates and size from it in exact pixels.

Comment: @codingVoldemort wow, that seems like major overkill.

Comment: If my client wants this tomorrow, that's what I would do. Meanwhile, I am thinking better ways. :P

Comment: This guy seems to have achieved a similar thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362407/nsattributedstring-background-color-and-rounded-corners

Comment: There MUST be a better way than that. @MorganWilde, hold on brother! :P