# NSAttributedString left spacing

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have an UITextView within NSAttributedString. And I need add some space before a letter. I need something like NSKernAttributeName, but for left spacing because NSKernAttributeName adds space on right side.

[image]

Comment: any hack or update?

Comment: @ChiragShah nope

Comment: Thats really sad! Giving this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362407/nsattributedstring-background-color-and-rounded-corners a shot. Hope I would have something positive :)

Comment: @ChiragShah also you can try to play with invisible characters. Who knows :)

Comment: you mean the space character? well I tried that but it doesnt match the expectations of the designer :'D

Answer (score -1):

```
textfield.leftView= [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 0)];
textfield.leftViewMode= UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
textfield.rightView= [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 0)];
textfield.UITextFieldViewMode= UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

try this man

Comment: Thanks. But I need to change the size of a letter.

Comment: give higher font ,