# How to set a corner radius for NSAttributedString's background?

Tags: ios, uilabel, core-text

I want to set a corner radius for partial text on UILabel. I've got the range.
The following code set the background color, but it gonna be a rectangle background.

So, my problem is **how to set a corner radius to it**?

```
string.setAttributes([NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red], range: range)
```

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: can you add some aditional code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSAttributedString background color and rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362407/nsattributedstring-background-color-and-rounded-corners)

Answer (score -7):

```
yourLabel.layer.backgroundColor  = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
yourLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5  //Change this value as your requirement
yourLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

May this code will help you.