# Highlight few different text in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel

Hi I would like to know how to display uilabel text in this form?

[image]

```
let str = value as? String
let updatedStr = str?.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "     ")
self.myInterestsLbl.text = updatedStr

//Highlight Text
let string = self.myInterestsLbl.text

if string?.range(of:"Fashion") != nil {
let fashion = "Fashion"
let range = (string! as NSString).range(of: fashion)
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: string!)                                     attributedText.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor(red: 0.98, green: 0.84, blue: 0.04, alpha: 1.0) , range: range)
self.myInterestsLbl.attributedText = attributedText
 }

if string?.range(of:"Gadgets") != nil {
let fashion = "Gadgets"
let range = (string! as NSString).range(of: fashion)
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: string!)                                         attributedText.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor(red: 0.98, green: 0.84, blue: 0.04, alpha: 1.0) , range: range)
self.myInterestsLbl.attributedText = attributedText
 }
```

During the actual debuging the updatedStr = "Fashion     Gadgets     Travel" but the highlight text doest not highlight all as shown at the picture below. The result I want is the above image.

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to say, your code showing output as you provided below.

Comment: If you are trying to say that Fashion and Gadgets both should have color change then check below answer, I have done some changes.

Comment: @Warewolf Hi, I've edited the question ad. The result I want is the first image. But for my code, the result display the image below.

Comment: @Warewolf Yes, Fashion and Gadgets need to highlight for both

Comment: you did mistake inside second if condition, check answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IBOutlet weak var myInterestsLbl:UILabel?


    let str = "Fashion Gadgets Travel";

    let updatedStr = str.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "     ");
    self.myInterestsLbl!.text = updatedStr;

    //Highlight Text
    let string = self.myInterestsLbl!.text;

    if string?.range(of:"Fashion") != nil {
        let fashion = "Fashion";
        let range = (string! as NSString).range(of: fashion);

        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: string!);
        attributedText.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor(red: 0.98, green: 0.84, blue: 0.04, alpha: 1.0) , range: range);
        self.myInterestsLbl!.attributedText = attributedText;
    }

    if string?.range(of:"Gadgets") != nil {
        let fashion = "Gadgets";
        let range = (string! as NSString).range(of: fashion);
        let attributedText = self.myInterestsLbl!.attributedText as? NSMutableAttributedString;  // You did mistake here. You were initialising it via String variable instead of changed attributed string.
        attributedText?.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor(red: 0.98, green: 0.84, blue: 0.04, alpha: 1.0) , range: range);
        self.myInterestsLbl!.attributedText = attributedText;
    }
```

Comment: but do you know how to make corner radius for the border?

Comment: for this you need to use library. if you are using pods  follow  https://github.com/zekunyan/TTGTagCollectionView  OR  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16423399/1305001 for attributed text