# How do you avoid UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() returning "nil" in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-text, uigraphicscontext

I'm trying to learn how to get rounded background highlighting via ([NSAttributedString background color and rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362407/nsattributedstring-background-color-and-rounded-corners))...

So I'm following [Apple's Core Text Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/LayoutOperations/LayoutOperations.html) and basically trying to recreate all the objective-C code in Swift.

I'm running into an error with `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` returning `nil`

Here's my ViewController, which gets pushed when a button gets tapped in a previous view:

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

public class HighlightPractiveViewController: UIViewController {

  override public func viewDidLoad() {
    drawRect()
  }

  func drawRect() {

    let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: view.bounds.size.height)
    context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    context.textMatrix = CGAffineTransform.identity

    let path = CGMutablePath()

    let bounds = CGRect(x: 10.0, y: 10.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0)
    path.addRect(bounds)


    let textString = NSString(string: "Hello, World!") // CF & NS are toll-free bridged.

    let attrString = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0)

    CFAttributedStringReplaceString(attrString, CFRangeMake(0, 0), textString)

    let rgbColorSpace: CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let components: [CGFloat] = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8]
    let red: CGColor = CGColor(colorSpace: rgbColorSpace, components: components)!

    CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrString, CFRangeMake(0, 12), kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, red)

    let framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString!)
    let frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, nil)

    CTFrameDraw(frame, context)
  }
}
```

How and where do I properly call `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` so that it doesn't return nil?

Comment: In Apple’s guide method drawRect() is UIView’s method, not UIControllerView. I guess you need to subclass UIView and implement its drawRect method and then you can add your custom view to UIViewController as subview of UIController’s view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to implement method drawRect() inside UIViewController. You have to do it inside your custom UIView.

```
class MyView: UIView {

   override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
      super.draw(rect)

      // write what you want to implement here
   }
}
```

Then add your custom MyView to UIViewControl's view hierarchy.

```
class HighlightPractiveViewController: UIViewController {

   func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad() // always call super's methods

      let myView = MyView()
      view.addSubview(myView)
   }  
}
```

Comment: I see! 

I added `override` to func draw(\_:) in the UIView-subclass.  

And also learned from documentation that _"You should never call this method [draw(\_:)] directly yourself._

Comment: Yes, you don't have to call this method. UI library calls it by itself before displaying the view on the screen.