# How to set UILabel (not UITextView) round corner background with NSMutableAttributedString?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel, nsmutableattributedstring

I need to get anyway to make code style in the UITableView.

Simple to make Blue Background

```
var dynamicBackground = #colorLiteral(red: 0.02708261088, green: 0.4768417478, blue: 0.9985074401, alpha: 1)
```

Then create NSMutableAttributedString in the UITableView

```
let attr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "if ", attributes: [.foregroundColor: KeyboardSyntax])
             
  attr.append(NSAttributedString(string: " false condition ", attributes: [.backgroundColor: dynamicBackground])). // Any idea to make background to round corner?
            
  attr.append(NSAttributedString(string: " {\n ", attributes: [.foregroundColor: PlainSyntax]))
            
  attr.append(NSAttributedString(string: "// Not execute\n", attributes: [.foregroundColor: CommentSyntax]))
            
  attr.append(NSAttributedString(string: "} ", attributes: [.foregroundColor: PlainSyntax]))
            
  attr.append(NSAttributedString(string: "else ", attributes: [.foregroundColor: KeyboardSyntax]))
            
  attr.append(NSAttributedString(string: "{\n ", attributes: [.foregroundColor: PlainSyntax]))
            
  attr.append(NSAttributedString(string: "// Execute\n", attributes: [.foregroundColor: CommentSyntax]))
               
  attr.append(NSAttributedString(string: "} ", attributes: [.foregroundColor: PlainSyntax]))
            
  cell.textLabel?.attributedText = attr
```

then display results
[image]

Thank you for your kind help. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSAttributedString background color and rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362407/nsattributedstring-background-color-and-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to customize NSLayoutManager and then addAttributes to your constructed NSAttributedString.  [NSAttributedString background color and rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362407/nsattributedstring-background-color-and-rounded-corners) will be helpful.

Comment: That is Objective C Verison. I can't understand that step to step in that answer.

Comment: @AntonioAdrianChavez I didn't see specific Objective-C code, I saw a step by step and these methods should have equivalent in Swift. You can search them and look how it is in Swift by swtiching the language in the doc and the other are in Swift, no?