# How to give space between text and underline with background color with corner radius for Attributed String in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, nsattributedstring

I am doing iOS application. I have requirement like I have to show particular text with underline and background color with some corner radius in my app.

I have tried below, I am able to show background color and underline, but I am not getting exact my requirement.

I have to show much space between **underline** and **iOS application** text. Also I have to show yellow background color with some rounded coreners.

Here is my code

```
  let text = "This is sample text for my iOS application this time"
    let range = (text as NSString).range(of: "iOS application" )
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

    attributedString.addAttribute(.underlineStyle,
                                  value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
                                  range: range)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.yellow , range: range)
    
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset, value: 2 , range: range)
    myLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to build a "Find Text on Page"-like behavior? What you've described may be beyond `NSAttributedString`'s standard abilities.

Comment: Using a third-party library like [this](https://github.com/instacart/Nantes/tree/e7ca4f54c19b057d7456b1cfa6d2c3fa0ecb8c30), you can achieve this may be

Comment: For corner radius https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362407/nsattributedstring-background-color-and-rounded-corners else, you'll need to play with `CoreText`, but nothing high level in iOS.

Comment: @Vym I am not sure its beyond NSAttributedString abilities, But I am trying to achieve

Comment: @Larme is it possible to set some space between text and underline from attributedstring?

Comment: Maybe by overriding `drawUnderline(forGlyphRange:underlineType:baselineOffset:lineFragmentRect:lineFragmentGlyphRange:containerOrigin:)`? But it's all low level, in `CoreText`.