Attributed string with background rounded corner in iOS Swift
enter image description here
I have two textView one is attributed string and other is html string so I want add background inside the span tag for elements and used this as attributed sting. attributed string provide us add background color in string but its does not provide us as a corner radius background. you can see my screenshot background is not inside the span tag its used wrong range and I think not match that's why my view is not lying in exact position where html span tag elements exist my code
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 let string = "LLorem Ipsum is simply <span>dummy</span> text of the printing and <span>typesetting industry</span>. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's <span>standard dummy</span> text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has <span>survived not</span> only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of <span>Lorem Ipsum.</span>"

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.isSelectable = true

        // Remove <span> tags from the string
        let cleanedString = removeSpanTags(from: string)

        // Set attributed text with paragraph styling
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: cleanedString)
        paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.25
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

        textView.attributedText = attributedString

        // Find ranges for <span> tags in the original string
        let pattern = "<span>([^<]+)</span>"
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
        let matches = regex.matches(in: string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, string.utf16.count))

        for match in matches {
            let matchRange = match.range(at: 1) // Use capture group 1
            let start = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: matchRange.lowerBound)
            let end = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: matchRange.upperBound - 1)
            let range = NSRange(location: start.utf16Offset(in: string), length: end.utf16Offset(in: string) - start.utf16Offset(in: string))

            if let frame = frameOfText(in: range, in: textView) {
                let view = UIView(frame: frame)
                view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0 // Add corner radius
                view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
                view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
                textView.addSubview(view)
            }
        }

        self.view.addSubview(textView)
    }

    func removeSpanTags(from htmlString: String) -> String {
        // Regular expression pattern to match and remove <span> tags
        let pattern = "<span>([^<]+)</span>"
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: htmlString.utf16.count)
        return regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: htmlString, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: "$1")
    }

    func frameOfText(in range: NSRange, in textView: UITextView) -> CGRect? {
        guard let start = textView.position(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, offset: range.location),
              let end = textView.position(from: start, offset: range.length),
              let textRange = textView.textRange(from: start, to: end) else {
            return nil
        }

        let rect = textView.firstRect(for: textRange)
        return textView.convert(rect, from: textView)
    }
}
}

please add background with corner radius where span tag elements exist in my string and also remove span tag from string and show me on screen as proper string

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362407/nsattributedstring-background-color-and-rounded-corners ?

sir basically i have this article in which article steps are written I cannot understand it if you have any other suggestion then please provide me
